# Splitting transaction order lines in two categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a bookkeeping application for a friend that runs a shop-in-shop. Basically, every product is owned by a seller.

They want an overview where they can see the value of how much money in a transaction was paid for their products (owned by seller 1) and how much money went to other products (seller != 1).

Here's the ERD: [image: ERD]

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT transaction.id, SUM(orderline.count), SUM(orderline.price), SUM(o1.price), SUM(o2.price), transaction.date
FROM transaction
JOIN orderline
  ON orderline.transaction_id = transaction.id
JOIN product
  ON product.barcode = orderline.product_barcode
JOIN orderline o1
  ON o1.transaction_id = transaction.id AND o1.product_barcode IN (SELECT barcode FROM product WHERE seller_id = 1)
JOIN orderline o2
  ON o2.transaction_id = transaction.id AND o2.product_barcode IN (SELECT barcode FROM product WHERE seller_id != 1)
GROUP BY transaction.id
```

Unfortunately, this only returns one transaction instead of all, and it doesn't return the correct sums of the prices either:

[image: Result]

In for transaction 77, the value of `SUM(o1.price)` should be 4.5, and that of `SUM(o2.price)` should be 0.95. The value of `SUM(orderline.price)` is correct.

I would like to instead get all transactions, and then the total value, value of products owned by seller 1 and value of products owned by seller != 1 (products should be part of the transaction, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TRANSACTION.id,
   Sum(orderline.count), 
   Sum(orderline.price),
   Sum( case when product.seller_id = 1 then  orderline.price else 0 end ), 
   Sum( case when product.seller_id <> 1 then  orderline.price else 0 end), 
   TRANSACTION.date
```

FROM   TRANSACTION 
       JOIN orderline
         ON orderline.transaction_id = TRANSACTION.id 
       JOIN product
         ON product.barcode = orderline.product_barcode
GROUP  BY TRANSACTION.id , TRANSACTION.date

Comment: This seems to work. Why do I need to group by transaction ID *and* transaction date?

Comment: If the 'sum, avg' function, such as the use of these functions must be used in each group by column.